# Fluid-framework Audience and member profile data

Tags: fluid-framework

I there a way to atach payload data to a member (myself) in the Audience. I have some client profile data which is better if kept in sync with user presence reflected by the Audience object. sort of like:

```
const clientId = audience.getMyself().connections[0].id;
audience.setMemberData(clientId, user.profile);
```

I know I can definitely create a SharedMap for that, but it seems like a waste maintaining  a separate DDS when there's already the Audience DDS w/ its Members.

Comment: This is not a supported feature yet, but would be a great addition to the repository...

Answer (score 0):

You can pass additional user data through the audience.

```
const userDetails: ICustomUserDetails = {
  email: "xyz@outlook.com",
  address: "Redmond",
};

const config = {
  tenantId: "myTenantId",
  tokenProvider: new AzureFunctionTokenProvider(
    "myAzureFunctionUrl" + "/api/GetAzureToken",
    { userId: "UserId", userName: "Test User", additionalDetails: userDetails }
  ),
  orderer: "https://myOrdererUrl",
  storage: "https://myStorageUrl",
};
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-fluid-relay/how-tos/connect-fluid-azure-service#adding-custom-data-to-tokens for more details.